# How do I mount a filesystem without the mount point changing owner to root?

Tags: debian, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I have two samba shares on a remote server (Debian 10, stable) on my home network. On my laptop (Debian 10 stable), I would like to automatically mount these shares to my local filesystem tree. To this end, I added these lines to my fstab file:

```
//cherver/sambaDocs /home/maquinisto/sambaDocs  cifs    credentials=/home/maquinisto/.smbcreds,user,rw  0 0
//cherver/sambaEtc  /home/maquinisto/sambaEtc   cifs    credentials=/home/maquinisto/.smbcreds,user,rw  0 0
```

My problem is that when fstab is read at boot or with `sudo mount -a`, the mount points change ownership to root, and I cannot write files there as a normal user. How do I mount these shares to my laptop system without the mount points changing owner to root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mount.cifs` allows the options `uid` and `gid` to specify the user, who "owns" the file system.

In you case the options (`credentials=/home/maquinisto/.smbcreds,user,rw`) would need to be extended to include `uid=xxxx` and if you so wish `gid=yyyy`